# I didn't find Microsoft Azure App Service option while clicking on publish my Bot Application

Tags: azure, bots

I developed simple bot application and ready to publish it into azure portal as "Microsoft Azure App Service"

but I didn't find this option while clicking on publish in my visual studio 2015. I get latest Microsoft Azure SDK 2.9.6 update from Tools and Extensions and updates option 
[image] Here is a screen shot.

Please provide root cause for resolve this issue.

Can you please help on this issue.

We are expecting is  :

[image]

Get it from https:// docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/gettingstarted.html

Comment: Are you publishing for Visual Studios? If so you need to login using your Azure subscription https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/microsoftimagine/2015/07/20/welcome-to-visual-studio-2015-with-azure/

Comment: Yes, I already logged in with Azure account into VS.  even though getting this issue

Answer (score 1):

You can try by downloading the "Get Publish Profile" option from the Azure portal and then using the import button in Visual Studio to publish

[Azure Portal Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVEYt.png)

Comment: Thank you Shawn Tjai for your answer. It's helped for me.

Answer (score 0):

For permanent solution I reset(user renamed my current user folder and relogin my system) my profile, now I am able to see this option under "select a publish target" when Project->RC->Publish